# Specify index prefix length in Grails domain using InnoDB as datasource

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In my Grails domain i currently have

```
String value
static constraints = {
    value(blank: false, size: 1..400)
}
static mapping = {
    value index: 'value_Idx'
}
```

My datasource is MySQL InnoDB which has a maximum index length of [767 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html).

Using UTF-8 this means maximum 255 characters which in turn means that a prefix index must be used.

In MySQL <= 5.5 I receive no error from Grails and when looking at the resulting index the prefix is silently adjusted to 255:

```
mysql> show index from table;
+--------+-------------+--------+----------+--------+
|  ....  | Column_name |  ....  | Sub_part |  ....  |
+--------+-------------+--------+----------+--------+
|  ....  | value       |  ....  | 255      |  ..... |
+--------+-------------+--------+----------+--------+
```

In MySQL 5.6 I receive an error during Grails application startup:

```
ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - Unsuccessful: create index value_Idx on table (value)
ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
```

This is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html) that states that:

> If you specify an index prefix length that is greater than the allowed
>   maximum value, the length is silently reduced to the maximum length.
>   In MySQL 5.6 and later, specifying an index prefix length greater than
>   the maximum length produces an error.

To support all versions of MySQL i which to specify the **prefix index length** explicitly in my domain class mapping. Is this possible? and how is this implemented?

I know how to do it in MySQL console but not how to do the similar in Grails/Gorm/Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Stepped on the same problem recently.

We used [Grails Database Migration Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) to archive that. Follow the installation steps provided in the docs and then create a new changelog `grails-app/migrations/add-prefixed-index.groovy` for example:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "authot", id: "addPrefixedIndex") {
        grailsChange {
            change {
                sql.execute('ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `value_Idx`(`value`(255));')
            }

            rollback {
                sql.execute('ALTER TABLE `table` DROP INDEX `value_Idx`;')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include your new file in the main database changelog: `include file: 'add-prefixed-index.groovy'`

Then run `grails dbm-update` and your new index is created.